# sublime SFTP with ppk file shows connection timeout from windows to Ubuntu14

Tags: sublimetext3, sftp

Hi I successfully connected to other ubuntu servers with sublime sftp before, but this time I don't understand why this settings doesn't work.

```
// sftp, ftp or ftps
"type": "sftp",
"host": "52.187.27.205",
"user": "root",
"remote_path": "/home",

"connect_timeout": 30,
"ssh_key_file": "C:\\pep.ppk",
//"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],
```

With the same settings,

I can connect from other Linux(the same key, but file path and format is different).
I can connect using Git BASH from my laptop(windows, same key file).
I can connect using Filezilla from my laptop(windows, same key file).

but I can't using only sublime SFTP.. any idea?